# How to test a function which returns void in google test?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, googletest

I have a function which needs to be tested but it returns `void`.

This function may modify some global variables.

For example:

```
/* target_code.h */

void add_num(int n);
```

```
/* target_code.c */

#include "target_code.h"

int number = 0;

void add_num(int n) {
    number += n;
}
```

(The real function I want to test is more complex than it.)

And I want to use the framework - google test for testing this function.

So  maybe I need to implement a test program to test it.

```
/* testProgram.cpp */
include "target_code.h"

/* implement the test case for it */
```

But this function doesn't return anything. It just modifies a global variable.

And in my coworker's point, it's not good to `extern` this variable `number` and check the value is correct or not in this example.

The one of the bad things is, maybe we will change the variable name about `number` and this test program may need to rewrite again (difficult to maintain).

But without this method, I don't know how to test this function works correctly or not.

A single method I thought is implementing a function which do the similar thing with `add_num`, and verifying this function.

Here is a example which I thought:

```
/* testProgram.cpp */

int fake_number = 0;
void fake_add_num(int n) {
    fake_number += n;
}

/* Implement the test cases */
```

This `fake_add_num` do the same thing with the real function "add_num". The different between them is I can reach this `fake_number` directly.

Maybe there are different methods to verify this kind of functions.

Please give me an example to do that. Thanks!!

Comment: *And in my coworker's point, it's not good to extern this variable number and check the value is correct or not in this example.* No, the problem is that you have a method modifying a global state in the first place. It should be changed to not rely on any global variables. If you absolutely can't do that, then `extern` is your only choice - you need to access that global variable somehow to check it. Or maybe the test is too granular and you should think about testing the code that uses `add_num`, not the function itself.

Comment: *"it's not good to `extern` this variable number*" it already is.

Comment: i dont get the point of the variable can change its name. Why is this a bad thing? Any function (also one with a return value) can have its name changed and then of course tests (and other code) may need to be adjusted.

Comment: in a nutshell testing is always the same, you set up the preconditions, you run the code to be tested, you assert the post conditions, (maybe some clean up afterwards). Thats it. Whether a global variable is involved or what a return type of a function is does not change how you test

Comment: on the other hand, if you find that code is difficult or impossible to test, then thats an issue of the code not of the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should figure out what the observable behavior of this function is and test that.  Everything else is implementation detail.

For example, if you have a companion to your `add_num` function:

```
void print_num() {
    std::cout << number << '\n';
}
```

Then the observable behavior of `add_num(2)` isn't "`number` is increased by 2", it's "The number printed by `print_num()` is increased by 2".  That is the behavior you should test.

For example, you could write a test like this:

```
TEST(NumTests, AddNumReflectedInPrintNum) {    
    init_num(0);
    testing::internal::CaptureStdout();
    print_num();
    ASSERT_EQ(testing::internal::GetCapturedStdout(), "0\n";)

    add_num(10);
    testing::internal::CaptureStdout();
    print_num();
    ASSERT_EQ(testing::internal::GetCapturedStdout(), "10\n";)
}
```

Note that the value of `number` is never tested anywhere.  That is an implementation detail.

Comment: I know what you mean. But the function I want to test is a memory and cache operation. This function `flush` or `invalidate` a cache and other hardware will read the memory. This test program may want to test if the function updates the cache and memory correctness.

Answer (score -1):

You can make an internal visible method (in some internal namespace) that tests uses it to get this global state and then you can do something like

```
// in header
namespace my_proj {
namespace internal {
int GetNumber() { return number; }
}
}

// in test
add_num(5);
EXPECT_EQ(expected_value, GetNumber());
```

One last thing, using global variables is not a recommended approach because of the issues it can introduce, so if you can avoid it, might be better.